# Get Number of sub accounts JPA

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa

I have very simple question - for which I could't find solution on google :)

I have a calls Company and sub class Clients

```
public class Company {
 private Long id;
 private String companyName;
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "companyID")
 private Set<Client> clients;
setters .. getters
}
```

how can I get count of clients without getting the whole company class and writing something like this:

```
public Company getClientsCount(Long companyID) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Company c where c.id =:companyID");
    q.setParameter("companyID", companyID);
    return (Company) q.getSingleResult();
}
```

and after:

```
int count = company.getCleints().size;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-aggregate-functions

Comment: Use count: 'select count(*) from Client c'

Comment: @Terzlya this is a joke yes?

Comment: @JBNizet I wasn't able to find answer there. I'm using JPA quarry language.

Comment: The link I gave explains that HQL/JPQL has a count aggregate function, and has no less than 3 examples showing how to use it. What else do you need?

Comment: @Irakli if you just searched a little you would see that you can use the _count_ within executeNativeQuery of your em(EntityManager)